# Editar lista que se agrega al formulario con un botón

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, formularios

Estoy armando un formulario en el cuál el usuario puede agregar campos haciendo click en un botón "agregar".
El problema es que estos campos están dentro de una lista, la cuál tiene un css, pero cuando se agregan más, éstos aparecen sin los estilos originales que les puse en el formulario. Para explicarme mejor, les dejo una demo del sitio que estoy haciendo: http://kickads.mobi/prevem/
Ahí podrán ver el error al que me refiero.
Lo que necesito es el código o saber qué hacer para que cuando agregue más campos al clickear en el botón, éstos respeten los estilos que tienen en el formulario.

Dejo también mi código:

```js
    $(function() {
  $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fieldList").append("<li>&nbsp;</li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='namehijos[]' placeholder='Nombre/s' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='number' name='age[]' placeholder='Edad' /></li>");
    $("#fieldList").append("<li><input type='text' name='gender[]' placeholder='Género' /></li>");
  });
});
```

```css
.lista {
display: inline;
width: 100%;    
}

.sonli {
float: left;   
width: 30%;    
}

.first {  
width: 32%;    
}

.second {
margin-left: 4%;   
}
```

```html
 <ul id="fieldList" style="padding: 0;list-style: none; overflow: hidden">
                                      <li class="sonli first">
                                      <label for="sons" class="radio-label">Nombre:</label>
                                      <input class="lista" name="namehijos[]" type="text" placeholder="Nombre/s" />
                                      </li>
                                      <li class="sonli second">
                                      <label for="sons" class="radio-label">Edad:</label>
                                        <input class="lista" name="age[]" type="number" placeholder="Edad" />
                                      </li>
                                      <li class="sonli second">
                                      <label for="sons" class="radio-label">Género:</label>
                                      <input class="lista" name="gender[]" type="text" placeholder="Género" />         
                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                       <button id="addMore" class="btn btn-large btn-success add" type="button">
                                  Agregar</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, a los append que estas realizando en

```
 $("#lista").append("<li><input /></li>");
```

Debes agregar el estilo que quieres dar

```
 $("#lista").append("<li class='sonli first'><input /></li>");
 $("#lista").append("<li class='sonli second'><input /></li>");
 $("#lista").append("<li class='sonli second'><input /></li>");
```

Comment: Esto era lo que necesitaba, gracias! Comparando tu código con lo que yo estaba intentando hacer, me di cuenta de que esto no me funcionaba porque ponía el nombre entre comillas dobles "" y no entre simples ''. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @CarlaPaludetto Si la respuesta de Hector ayudo a resolver tu problema, marca la respuesta como aceptada (✓).

Comment: @VickMuñoz si, ahora la marco cuando pasen los 3 minutos que me pide para marcar una respuesta. Gracias!